# A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to expression tree with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

As I'm trying to directly use

```
_applicatonDbContext.LineCustomFields
.Where(lcf => lcf.BillLineId == Convert.ToInt64(cu.LineId))
```

It gives `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 ToInt64(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` on runtime.

Now as I'm trying to achieve.

```
.Where(lcf =>
{
   long bigval = Convert.ToInt64(cu.LineId);
   return lcf.BillLineId == bigval;
})
```

It gives `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to expression tree` compile error how can I convert the right hand operand to match with left without giving `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ...` on runtime.
Now I've got multiple inner queries which require Id to check another entity and that requires conversion as well.

**Update 1:**

```
bill.Line = _applicatonDbContext.BillLines
                            .Where(bl => bl.BillLineId == Convert.ToInt64(b.BillId))
                            .Select(cu => new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line
                            {
                                Id = cu.LineId.ToString(),
                                LineNum = cu.LineNum,
                                Amount = (decimal)Helper.GetConvertedStringToDecimal(cu.Amount),
                                AmountSpecified = (bool)cu.AmountSpecified,
                    
                                CustomField = _applicatonDbContext.LineCustomFields
                                              .Where(lcf => lcf.BillLineId == Convert.ToInt64(cu.LineId))
                                              .Select(cf => new CustomField
                                              {
                                                  DefinitionId = cf.DefinitionId,
                                                  Name = cf.Name,
                                                  AnyIntuitObject = cf.AnyIntuitObject.ToString(),
                                                  Type = (CustomFieldTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(CustomFieldTypeEnum), cf.Type.ToString())
                                              }).ToArray(),
```

Here `.Where(bl => bl.BillLineId == Convert.ToInt64(b.BillId))` is parent and `.Where(lcf => lcf.BillLineId == Convert.ToInt64(cu.LineId))` is child. it is an example to show that query and sub query exists within it.

Comment: What is `b.BillId`? Where did it come from? What is the type of `bl.BillLineId`? What is the type of `lcf.BillLineId`? EF & EF Core are different - which tag is correct? What is the version? What is the database provider?

Comment: @NetMage `foreach(var b in unmatchedBills)` so `b.BillId` comes from it even though I use `long billId = Convert.ToInt64(b.BillId)` the inner query will still ask for conversion of parent Id afterwards.

Comment: Please show all relevant code. Where is parent Id referenced in inner query? C# is a language of types. What is the type of `cu.LineId`? Why do you need both `ToString` and `Convert.ToInt64` for the same object?

Answer (score 0):

You wont' be able to do this in one query because of the disparity in data types and conversion issues (as you have found out).

You'll need to break this down into multiple calls. First load the lines:

```
var billId = Convert.ToInt64(b.BillId);
bill.Line = _applicatonDbContext.BillLines
            .Where(bl => bl.BillLineId == billId)
            .Select(cu => new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Line
            {
                Id = cu.LineId.ToString(),
                LineNum = cu.LineNum,
                Amount = (decimal)Helper.GetConvertedStringToDecimal(cu.Amount),
                AmountSpecified = (bool)cu.AmountSpecified
            }).ToArray();
```

Then load the custom field data for each line:

```
foreach(var billLine in bill.Line)
{
    var lineId = Convert.ToInt64(billLine.Id);
    billLine.CustomField = _applicatonDbContext.LineCustomFields
              .Where(lcf => lcf.BillLineId == lineId)
              .Select(cf => new CustomField
              {
                  DefinitionId = cf.DefinitionId,
                  Name = cf.Name,
                  AnyIntuitObject = cf.AnyIntuitObject.ToString(),
                  Type = (CustomFieldTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(CustomFieldTypeEnum), cf.Type.ToString())
              }).ToArray();
}
```

In both operations, the assumption is that the target properties are enumerables (although the name suggests a single entity, you are using `Select` to populate them). Modify the code accordingly if that is not the case.

Comment: It is using sub queries `Convert.ToInt64(cu.LineId);` parent entity which is calling child entity and so on and so forth.

Comment: @namco Don't you think it would be a good idea to include that part of the code too so we have the whole picture and don't have to ask? :-)

Comment: yeah sure I'll update the query above.

Comment: I knew the answer which you've repeated here, but I was thinking there might have been an alternative way to directly use conversion on `where` clause as this would really create more lines of code unnecessarily, but thank you for the update.

Comment: @namco You need to understand why you are getting these errors. Simply put, the compiler is trying to convert your code to something that can execute in your data store and there is nothing equivalent. You should have mentioned that you "already knew the answer" so I wouldn't waste my time trying to help you.

Comment: I should've updated the question and the summary briefly sorry to have wasted your time.